# Spring Data JPA delete causes OutOfMemoryError on WebSphere

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, websphere-8

Spring Data JPA deletion causes OutOfMemoryError after it was deployed on WebSphere 8.5.5. But it runs fine on Tomcat deployed with Spring Boot connecting to the same database. The entity that it tries to delete has many bi-directional ManyToOne references to children entities. The data set on an Oracle 11g database is very small. The deletion runs fine with other entities that do not have child. I have tried using both WebSphere and Apache OpenJPA persistence providers. My system output shows it stuck at a long select statement and consumed all available memory. The select statement is generated by JPA Hibernate. The same select call is running fine on Tomcat configured with Spring Boot. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options:

- configure Websphere to make more memory available to your application.
- tune your mapped relationships (i.e. remove them or remove the cascading) so you can delete in smaller batches.
- use SQL to perform the deletion.

The underlying problem is that JPA promises to create events when deleting entities, therefore it has to load entities before deleting them.